# how to get element height in mootools 1.1

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am trying to get the height of a `li`, am new to **mootools** and using version 1.1...

My Code which have tried:-

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){ 
   alert($('#slider_more li').getSize().y);
});

myMore.start(425*2); //and implement in the place of 425
```

Also want to know if their is a feature with mootools as height set to auto??

Comment: Any particular reason for using a several year old version of Mootools instead of the 1.4.5 most recent?

Comment: yes i have a plugin which runs with mootools1.1 not in 1.4.5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$$('#slider_more li')[0].getSize().size.y`.

http://jsfiddle.net/SW3tP/1/

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/5DvnB/, this answer is perfectly valid. The problem is that you should be using $$, not $, which just works for retrieving by ID, not by CSS selector.

Comment: I added a fiddle as well, using the selector the way you intended to do in your post.